# How to Vlookup a filtered list

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am trying to figure out how to lookup information in a filtered table, returning only visible values.

For example, the data I want to use for the lookup is in cell A3, the lookup data is in another sheet in cells `A2:E264`. A normal lookup function would be `=VLOOKUP(A3,'[IBD.xlsx]IBD'!$A$2:$E$264,2,FALSE)`. But if I then autofilter the data in `A2:E264` such that some rows are hidden, I only want the vlookup function to return a value if the data from A3 is also in a VISIBLE cell in `A2:E264`, otherwise it should return an error.

Answer (score 0):

`=INDEX([IBD.xlsx]IBD!$A:$E,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW([IBD.xlsx]IBD!$A$2:$E$264)/(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET([IBD.xlsx]IBD!$A$2,ROW([IBD.xlsx]IBD!$A$2:$E$264)-MIN(ROW([IBD.xlsx]IBD!$A$2:$E$264)),))*([IBD.xlsx]IBD!$A$2:$E$264=A3)),1),2)`

though such a construction will not work if the source workbook is closed.

Regards

Comment: Many thanks for this. When i try to use i get #NAME? Error even though everything looks correct. Any suggestions?
Thanks once again!

Comment: Ah, you're on a version of Excel prior to 2010?

Comment: it is the latest, 2016

Comment: Perhaps I miscopied your file/sheet name. Looks like that in the formula you posted has single apostrophes round it.